# ChangeGuru - Panaya - deep analysis of fields/profiles/etc REPLACEMENT?

Tags: force.com, query

I am a user of the ChangeGuru product by Panaya, but apparently the product is being end of lifed. Does anyone have another tool or other ways to analyze the impact of a field (on apex classes, apex triggers, reports, page layouts, workflows, validation rules, etc.) without manually searching through each field?  Basically, is there a quick way to tell how each field is used and where?

Comment: Does field trip help https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4?

Comment: I do use Field trip. It doesn't dive into Where and How the field is used on reports, validation rules and workflows. Field Trip for me is super helpful to get an idea if a field is being used (esp if it's new with a new business process), but it misses being able to see the reports its used in.

Answer (score 1):

I wish there was anything that came remotely close to what Panaya offered but I'm not aware of anything.

You essentially are left with exporting your metadata (in eclipse, or easier via the package builder app on [sftoolkit.co](http://sftoolkit.co)) and use good old fashioned search / find tools.

You can do search/find in eclipse which will allow you to search for API names of fields and such, but its nothing like what you get from panaya.

If you are a command line ninja, you can probably have some luck with using commands like [GREP](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html) (note that [BASH works on windows now too](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about)!) but it takes some expertise.

I've been working (slowly) on using open refine (openrefine.org) to parse metadata XML files for analysis, which works well for some scenarios ([like page layouts](http://goravseth.com/determining-which-fields-are-used-in-a-page-layout)) but i think could fail on scenarios like reports, since there would be so many files (one per report).

There is [an idea for some native impact assessment functionality](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpqdAAC) that has a decent number of votes.

I truly wish there was any tool that could do half of what Panaya <strike>does</strike> did.

Answer (score 1):

We also used ChangeGuru and was super sad to see it go.  This is the best replacement we have found.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI

Not as robust or amazing as ChangeGuru but is the best we have found.

Answer (score 0):

[happysoup.io](https://happysoup.io) is a community-led, free, and open-source project which  allows you to perform impact analysis for Salesforce. It provides similar capabilities to what you are looking for.

PS: I'm not trying to sell anything, as stated above the site is **FREE** and it is a good alternative to ChangeGuru, which is exactly what this question is all about.